# Mutation of numeric Data into "high" "medium" and "low" produced between() called on numeric vector with S3 class

Tags: r, vector, numeric, mutation

I tried to produce a mutation of numeric data into "high","medium" and "low" via

```
library(dplyr)

mdata %>%
  mutate(mvariable = case_when(vari < quantile(vari,0.5) ~ 'low', 
                      between(vari, quantile(vari, 0.5), quantile(vari, 0.75))~'med', 
                      TRUE ~ 'high'))
```

to use it in a multi level analysis.

It didn't generate my desired data but told me:

**between() called on numeric vector with S3 class**

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

I am using R version 4.1.2 -- "Bird Hippie"

Comment: Can you please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: oh, what did I do wrong. Should I always quote/mention that under a question?

Comment: The main point here is that we don#t know how your data looks like and what `vari` is, so it is important that you add an example of your data to your post that we can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative solution (without knowing the data) could be to circumvent the `between` function entirely by switching the order of the `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mdata <- mdata %>%
  mutate(mvariable = case_when(vari < quantile(vari, 0.5) ~ 'low',
                               vari > quantile(vari, 0.75) ~ 'high', 
                               TRUE ~ 'med'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. No error so far. But the data do not appear in my mvariable data. (searched over and over). :( It just shows my as an output all data from which my vari belongs (its a mean of them).

Comment: Because the code just prints the result. You need to assign it to your object if you want to store it (see my update).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the update. (I am a total newbie here). Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot <3

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `base::cut()`?

```
library(dplyr)

mdata %>% 
  mutate(mvariable = cut(vari, 
                         breaks=c(-Inf, 0.5, 0.75, Inf), 
                         labels=c("low", "med", "high")))
```

When labeling, labels requires n-numbers of breaks - 1. I.e, labels = breaks - 1.
So if you have 5 breaks you need 4 labels, 4 breaks 3 labels and so on.

**EDIT:**

You could also use dynamic quantiles which changes depending on your data.

```
library(dplyr)

mdata %>% 
  mutate(mvariable = cut(vari, 
                         breaks=c(-Inf, quantile(vari)[3], quantile(vari)[4], Inf), 
                         labels=c("low", "med", "high")))
```

Comment: Thank a lot. Also here both codes worked out (no error). But the data hasn't changed. The variable in data= mdata is still named "vari" instead of "mvariable" and there is also no new column with the label "mvariable" :( Do you have an idea regarding that?

Comment: You never assigned it. Use mdata <- mdata %>% and the rest of the code.